# How to pass new field value from sale order line to invoice lines while using down payment in odoo 15

Tags: odoo-15

How to pass new field value from sale order  line to invoice  lines while using down payment in odoo 15

Answer (score 0):

**Usefull basics**:

The model sale.order.line is related to the model account.move.line through this field:

**invoice_lines**: list of invoice lines (account.move.line) linked to this sale.order.line

And the corresponding relational field in account.move.line to sale.order.line is:

**sale_line_ids**: list of sale order lines (sale.order.line) linked to this account.move.line

**1. Create a new field**

To create a new field in the model you want: (App) Configuration > (Menu) Technicals > Fields
Create new field in the model you want (account.invoice.line ?)
Example : mynewfield

**2. Create an automated Action**

Create an automated action using (App) Configuration > (Menu) Technicals > automated Actions
Or: can be found here : /web?debug=1#id=&action=435&model=base.automation)
Create a new one, on the model sale.order.line
Action: execute python code

```py
        #Update invoice lines corresponding to the current sale.order.line-record:
        for invoice_line_record in record.invoice_lines:
           invoice_line_record['mynewfield'] = record['invoiced']
```